# a question about Spring controller

Tags: spring, controller

a piece of code like this:

```
@Controller  
public class HomeController {
  public static final int DEFAULT_SPITTLES_PER_PAGE = 25;
  private SpitterService spitterService;
  @Inject                     
  public HomeController(SpitterService spitterService) {
    this.spitterService = spitterService;
  }
  @RequestMapping({"/","/home"})        
  public String showHomePage(Map<String, Object> model) {

    model.put("spittles",
              spitterService.getRecentSpittles(DEFAULT_SPITTLES_PER_PAGE));              
    return "home"; 
  }
}
```

I confused is the servlet know pass what to a method? In this example it pass a Map model to showHomePage, I want to know where is the model from and what contains in the model?

The method not need to pass the model to a view, the servlet will implicitly pass the argument model to view?

Answer (score 1):

you should study [the extended Spring documentation on @RequestMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

It explains that the String returned by the method will be interpreted as a View name, and the map passed as argument will serve to enrich the model passed to the view

cheers

Grooveek